# Using git tags or commits in container images in Azure pipeline

Tags: azure-pipelines, git-tag

My question is about using git tags for our container images into Azure pipelines. Is there any way in Azure pipeline to make this in an automated way. If this is not the case, what can be a good solution to use git commits ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you could use **Powershell** task to get the current tag like `git describe --tag` and then set the tag's value to a new pipeline custom variable. And then set the variable into container image.